# Can we configure our Bluemix chatbot Application with Multiple Conversation Workspace?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Can we configure our Bluemix chatbot Application with Multiple Conversation Workspace? If yes then how we can call to particular conversation service on the basis of user questions asked on chatbot?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by your application. A scenario could be that

- the user input is analyzed by your app or by sending it to the [national language classifier](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-classifier/getting-started.html#natural-language-classifier) or [NL understanding service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/natural-language-understanding/).
- based on the results of the analysis your app would then send the input to the specific workspace
- calls into a conversation workspace are stateless, but have an ID for the individual conversation (chat) and metadata about where in the dialog you are
- that info could be used to later jump back to where in the conversation for a workspace the user was

IMHO, that technique could be used to support multiple spoken languages or to separate different more complex subjects into individual workspaces. [Take a look at the architecture diagram in the documentation for the general idea](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#about).